# Issue With Edit Record using Ajax Jquery In Asp.Net?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I m working with Jquery Ajax and performing crud operation,

I want to update a record and When I click the update button then fill(means name and address) the form data and then changes of name or address then again press edit button my edit button should not be work?

getlistdata function display the employee list.

How to edit a record?

How to resolve this issue??

Emploee.aspx

```
<input type="button" id="btnsubmit" value="Submit" onclick="insertrecord()" />

<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" Value="" />
```

```
//for insert

function insertrecord() {

                    EmpId = $('HiddenField').val();

                    if ($("#btnsubmit").val() == "Submit") {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'Emploee.aspx/insertdata',
                            type: 'POST',
                            contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                            dataType: 'json',
                            data: "{name:'" + $("#txtName").val() + "',address:'" + $("#txtAddress").val() + "'}",
                            success: function (data) {
                                //alert(data.d);
                                alert("Insert Data Successfully");
                                 if(data.d)
                                {
                                    window.location.reload();
                                }

                            },
                            Error: function () {
                                alert("Insert Error");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //when I press again edit button(means change name and address) then the record should not be updated that is my problem??

                        $.ajax({

                            url: 'Emploee.aspx/edit',
                            type: 'post',
                            contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                            datatype: 'json',
                            data: "{EmpId: '" + EmpId + "'}",
                            success: function (data) {
                                data = JSON.parse(data.d);
                            },
                            error: function () {
                                alert('Update Error');
                            },
                        });
                    }
                }

                   function getlistdata() {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'Emploee.aspx/GetEmpData',
                        type: 'get',
                        contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (data) {
                            //alert(data.d);
                            //exit();
                            data = JSON.parse(data.d);
                            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                                $("#tbl").append('<tr><td>' + data[i].EmpName + '</td><td>' + data[i].EmpAge + '</td><td>' + data[i].EmpAddress + '</td> 

<td><input type="button" id="btnedit" value="Edit" onclick="EditData(' + data[i].EmpId + ',\'' + data[i].EmpName + '\',\'' + data[i].EmpAddress + '\')" /></td> </tr>');
                            }
                        },
                        Error: function () {
                            alert("get error");
                        }
                    });
                }

                function EditData(EmpId, EmpName, EmpAddress) {
                    $.ajax({

                        url: 'Emploee.aspx/updates',
                            type: 'post',  
                            contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',  
                            datatype: 'json',  
                            data: "{EmpId: '" + EmpId + "',EmpName:'" + $("#txtName").val() + "',EmpAddress:'" + $("#txtAddress").val() + "'}",
                            success: function (data) {  

                                data = JSON.parse(data.d);  
                                EmpId = EmpId;
                                $("#txtName").val(EmpName);
                                $("#txtAddress").val(EmpAddress);

                                if (EmpId != null) {
                                    $("#btnsubmit").val("Update");
                                }  
                            },  
                            error: function () {  
                                alert('Update Error');  
                            },

                        });
                    }

            </script>
```

Emploee.aspx.cs

```
        [WebMethod]  //update (fill form data) when press update button click
        public static void updates(int EmpId, string EmpName, string EmpAddress)
        {
            cn.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update", cn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpId", EmpId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpName", EmpName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpAddress", EmpAddress);
            int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cn.Close();

            if (i>0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("successfully updated");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("successfully Not updated");
            }
        }
```

```
        [WebMethod] (when fillable updated record changes then again press update button)
        public static string Edit(int EmpId, string EmpName, string EmpAddress)
        {
            string _data = "";
            cn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("editsp", cn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpId", EmpId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpName", EmpName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpAddress", EmpAddress);

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            cn.Close();
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                _data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds.Tables[0]);
            }
            return _data;
        }
```

update store procedure

update (fill the form record(name and address) when pressing the update button )

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[update]
    @EmpId int,
    @EmpName varchar(40),
    @EmpAddress varchar(30)
AS
BEGIN
    update tblEmployee set EmpName=@EmpName,EmpAddress=@EmpAddress where EmpId=@EmpId
END
```

edit (fillable record update(means name and address change) then pressing the again update button

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[edit]
    @EmpId int,
    @EmpName varchar(30),
    @EmpAddress varchar(20)
AS
BEGIN
    select * from tblEmployee where EmpId=EmpId or EmpName=EmpName or EmpAddress=EmpAddress; 
END
```

see browser logs :

[image]

[image]

what should be doing I m wrong?

Answer (score 1):

u will change it

function **EditData**(empid,empname,empaddress,empage) {

Comment: Enis Cannot read property '0' of null when I m passing this parameter ``` data: "{empid:'" + empid + "',empname:'" + empname + "',empaddress:'" + empaddress + "',empage:'" + empage + "'}"```

Answer (score 0):

use same property of your  webmethod
Ex.

public static void update(int id, string name, int age, string address)

Your data should be

id:'" + empid + "',name:'" + empname + "',address:'" + empaddress + "',age:'" + empage

Comment: Enis can u help more and I made some changes my code    When I click the update button then fill the form data and changes of name or address then again press edit button my edit button should not be work??

Comment: ```if (EmpId != null) {
                                    $("#btnsubmit").val("Update");
                                } ```            I m writing this function because else part work but form changes data should not be work??

Answer (score 0):

change the getlistdata

```
            function getlistdata() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'Emploee.aspx/GetEmpData',
                    type: 'get',
                    contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
            data = JSON.parse(data.d);
                      $.each(data, function (index, element) {
            debugger
            $("#tbl").append('<td>' + element.EmpName  + '</td>');
            $("#tbl").append('<td>' + element.EmpAddress + '</td>');
            $("#tbl").append('<td><input type="button" id="btnedit" value="Edit" onclick="EditData(' + element.EmpId + ', \'' + element.EmpName + '\' ,\'' + element.EmpAddress + '\')" /></td>');
                        });


                    },
                    Error: function () {
                        alert("get error");
                    }
                });
            }
```

change editdata and take hiddenfield

```
            function EditData(EmpId, EmpName, EmpAddress) {
                $.ajax({

                    url: 'Emploee.aspx/updates',
                    type: 'post',
                    contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                    datatype: 'json',
                    data: "{EmpId: '" + EmpId + "',EmpName:'" + $("#txtName").val() + "',EmpAddress:'" + $("#txtAddress").val() + "'}",
                    success: function (data) {

                        data = JSON.parse(data.d);

                        $("#txtName").val(EmpName);
                        $("#txtAddress").val(EmpAddress);
                          $("#HiddenField1").val(EmpId);

                        if (EmpId != null) {
                            $("#btnsubmit").val("Update");
                        }
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert('Update Error');
                    },

                });
            }
```

else part

```
function saverecord() {
EmpId = $("#HiddenField1").val();

else{

                    $.ajax({

                        url: 'WebForm1.aspx/updates',
                        type: 'post',
                        contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                        datatype: 'json',
                        aync: true,
                        data: "{EmpId: '" + EmpId + "',EmpName:'" + $("#txtName").val() + "',EmpAddress:'" + $("#txtAddress").val() + "'}",
                        success: function (data) {

                            window.location.reload();

                        },
                        error: function () {
                            alert('Update Error');
                        },
                    });
                }
```